# Using Engine class in an other Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I have an Engine A which manage the model `users` (Note that I cannot modify this Engine).

I have a second Engine B where I would like to set a new method for `users` class.

In the Engine A the user model is declared as follow :

```
  Module Check
     class User
     end
  end
```

I tried to use this class in engine_b/models/user, with the same syntax :

```
  Module Check
     class User
       def my_new_method
         ...
       end
     end
  end
```

But the method is not working. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Engine B knows about Engine A, I think what you may need is a `class_eval`. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240948/how-to-extend-a-model-in-a-rails-engine-from-another-rails-engine) for reference on how you could potentially use this.